# Slowing down a while loop that is moving an image view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, while-loop

When I call this method:

```
- (void)method:(int)i {
    while (image[i].center.y <= 100) {
        image[i].center = CGPointMake(image[i].center.x, image[i].center.y+2);
    }
}
```

The loop instantly runs and the image is instantly brought to the point where y=100. Is there a way of slowing this (or an alternative I am unaware of) that will let the image visually move or accelerate to the point rather that instantly moving to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you are looking to make an animation, maybe something like this.

```
- (void)method:(int)i {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                    animations:^{ 
                      image[i].center = CGPointMake(image[i].center.x, 100);
                    }];
}
```

I recommend you read this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using code similar to this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x, image.center.y-moveAmount);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```